# SQL: Return all records ignoring duplicates based on a field in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a database looking like:

```
Incremental_ID | First Name | Last Name | Email | Data1 | Data2 | Concat
```

This database contains one million records about approximately 200,000 customers that has been put together from various other databases, so one record might have `Data1` and another might have no `Data1` but instead `Data2`. In order to find duplicates, I created the record `Concat` which contains all customer data found in every file (First Name, Last Name, Email) in order to have a unique value per customer.

How can I tell postgresql to return every line unless the `concat` value has already been returned?

Comment: I assume the data is different, else `Distinct` might be an option.  But if there are duplicates, how are you determining which record to return?

Comment: I dont quite understand, that last line suggests that you just want `where concat is null`.  But I dont see how the `data` columns fit in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (concat) t.*
from table t
order by concat, incremental_id;
```

This will return the first row for each "concat" based on the `incremental_id`.